# EJB3 initialization code

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I've searched this for a while now, but can't seem to find an answer to this. How can I execute some code in when deploying an EJB3 jar-file to a JBoss server? For example, I need to run some sql migration scripts before the beans are ready to be used.

Comment: I have an answer, but it starts with "First, upgrade to JBoss 7 ...", so probably not a lot of use to you, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use EJB 3.1 (with @Singleton @Startup), I would recommend packaging your EJB module in an EAR with a WAR. Add a ServletContextListener to the WAR, and take your action in the contextInitialized method.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be one good way to accomplish this. However, we decided to use JBoss extension of EJB3 called Service POJOs. These services have start methods that get invoked while deploying the application. I realize this is not a standard way, but since we are stuck with JBoss, this seems to be the easiest way to run db migration code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a JBoss MBean service with a Listener that can perform any initialization (SQL scripts run in your case) after JBoss is fully started and before any EJB is used.
I have created such a service and we run it on JBoss 4.2.3.GA, so, you do not need to migrate to JBoss 7.